# best way to update page content every 15s using .net core

Tags: .net, static, paging

i have implemented one web app with .net core to display some info from company. it will display on a screen in front of the company gate on a few pages, depends on the items number. the pages need to auto update and paging every 15s.

what I have done, i dont find very elegant:

1. I read all the items from DB and order them by publish date, calculate the height defined by the user and group into several pages, save this info into a dictionary. so each page contains several items and the sum of their height <= 100%. The refresh was done by another App, every 15s that app make a new request.
2. I defined a static pagenumber in controller, every refresh I will check the current pagenumber and retrieve the items on this pagenumber from DB, then pagenumber++.

what I dont like about this Implementation is:

1. User told me that they dont see all items from one round of autopaging.
2. in my controller I calculate each time and save the page items info dictionary
3. is there better way instead of this static var for me to store current pagenummber, in order to update it next refresh?
4. sometimes the page is empty, this I need to debug but I have the feeling that it is a problem from this static pagenumber.

thank you for your advices in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You mean to say that you need to refresh the page and get the updated data every 15 seconds.

The best way to do it is using Jquery:

First import the JQuery script through its cdn link:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then

```
$(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
       window.location.reload(true); // true means it will force reload
}, 15000);
```

15000 means 15 thousand milliseconds and that is 15 seconds (because 1 sec = 1000 millisecond)

Comment: thank you for your reply. no, i want to pagination the table info within given Intervals. it works now.